Sort strings logically in SQL with digit parts sorted as numerical values
I've got a table with codes such as 11, 101 ST-1001, ST-100 etc. and I want to sort the data so that the integer parts are sorted as their integer values. But the problem it's mixed up with string/varchar parts as well.
So, is it possible in MS-SQL to sort codes "logically" in the same way as the Windows StrCmpLogicalW dll function?
I've tried sorting it using a CASE statement, but I think this will become too complex if it has to take into account all the different string prefixes. See example code below.
CREATE TABLE metaforms (
    Code varchar(10),
    Description varchar(25),
    Variables integer
);
GO

INSERT INTO metaforms (
    Code,
    Description,
    Variables
) VALUES
('1', 'testform', 143),
('10015', 'measurement', 16),
('1020006510', 'Nutrition history', 50),
('1010010006', 'Translator', 8),
('10200310', 'Delivery Details: I', 13),
('10200320', 'Delivery Details: II', 12),
('10200330', 'Delivery Details: III', 12),
('1020100001', 'Comfort and Hygiene', 10),
('1020100025', 'Car Seat Evaluation', 7),
('1020100053', 'Length Weight', 7),
('AMB-100', 'AMB SF SA-DIABETES', 5),
('AMB-34', 'AMB SF SA-CHEST', 5),
('AMB-99', 'AMB SF SA-COUGH', 5),
('LQF-3912', 'DLBX-M DIAGNOSTICS (3912)', 21),
('LQF-40', 'DLBX-M DIAGNOSTICS (40)', 24),
('LQF-588', 'DLBX-M DIAGNOSTICS (588)', 34),
('ST-1010', 'Standard form 1010', 9),
('ST-200', 'Standard form 200', 9),
('ST-35', 'Standard form 35', 9);

-- try sorting
select * from metaforms
order by case when isnumeric(code)=1 then right('000000000000'+code, 12) else code end;

select * from metaforms order by LEN(code), code;

select * from metaforms
order by case when isnumeric(code)=1 then LEN(code) end, code;

The select statements in the code above sorts the numeric values correctly, but not the codes that also have a string part.
So the desired sorted result should be like this:
Code
-----------
1
10015
10200310
10200320
10200330
1010010006
1020006510
1020100001
1020100025
1020100053
AMB-34
AMB-99
AMB-100
LQF-40
LQF-588
LQF-3912
ST-35
ST-200
ST-1010


The best option here might be to store the text prefix and numeric suffix in separate bona fide columns.  The query for what you want will be ugly and non performant.

The pattern in your example data always has numbers, sometimes preceded by a string and a dash. So you could mess around with charindex('-') and sort both parts individually. Of course, for daily use you may prefer keeping the parts separate in the table, or adding leading zeroes, if possible.

An SQLCLR function using StrCmpLogicalW directly might be the most accurate, if slow. And this is the reason you shouldn't store multiple pieces of info in a single column.

If all your data indeed matches the shown pattern ^([A-Z]*-|)[0-9]+$, we can take advantage of the - also denoting negative numbers. So instead of fucking around with stuff like “charindex + 1”, we just take the absolute value.
select *
from #metaforms
order by left(code, charindex('-', Code))
    , abs(substring(code, charindex('-', Code), 999999999))

Alternatively you could do this. Probably better actually?
select *
from #metaforms
order by left(code, charindex('-', Code))
    , cast(right(code, len(code) - charindex('-', Code)) as int)

Output:
1
10015
10200310
10200320
10200330
1010010006
1020006510
1020100001
1020100025
1020100053
AMB-34
AMB-99
AMB-100
LQF-40
LQF-588
LQF-3912
ST-35
ST-200
ST-1010


Thanks, I think this is the best answer without having to add custom functions. I wanted to call the StrCmpLogicalW function by doing create assembly shlwapi from 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll' but apparently the shlwapi.dll is not a pure .NET assembly so not managed using CLR so it cannot be used in MSSQL

Just want to mention I've posted a custom T-SQL function that more generally solves this and comes close to what StrCmpLogicalW does, see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/78720045/1745616
